# Is it possible to dedicate a gear for database usage?

Tags: database, openshift

I have a DIY app setup with nginx and php55. Is it possible to run a separate app dedicated to mysql and remotely connect to it? What would be the steps involved?

Answer (score 3):

The workaround is to create another scalable application using any web cartridge and MySQL database. When you create a scalable application web cartridge eg PHP and database cartridge like MySQL are installed on separate gears. The MySQL DB would get installed on separate gear and you can access that in your DIY PHP55 application. But this would mean you will have to waste your one gear running web cartridge.